# My program collapses when trying to connect to invalid host and port

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm proggramming client and server for chat room (using PyQt5).
I have a function which gets ip and port and connects a global socket to that ip and port. I want that function to return True if it could connect and False if it could'nt connect to that ip and port. every time that I'm inserting invalid host and port my program just collapses.

I tried using socket.settimeout(TIME) but it doesn't work.

```py
def connect_to_client(host, port):
    global client_socket
    adr = (host, port)
    client_socket.settimeout(4)
    client_socket.connect(adr)
    if client_socket is None:
        return False
    print ("Established connection")
    return True
```

Comment: By "collapses" I assume you mean you get an exception? What exception do you get? Perhaps it's an exception saying "can't connect" that you should catch and in its handler return `False`?

Comment: Also note that since `client_socket` is an object instance of some class, an object which you have created somewhere, then it will *never* be `None` (unless the creation of the object failed, in which case calling member functions on the object would fail with exceptions).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude by collapses I mean the script just stops with the following message: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 There is no exception so I can't use try and except.

Comment: Do you insist on _using socket.settimeout(TIME)_?